# Project Tango: Depthmap Transformation from XYZij data

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm currently trying to filter the depth information using OpenCV. For that reason I need to transform Project Tango's depth information XYZij into a image like depthmap. (Like the output of Microsoft Kinect) Unfortunately the official APIs [lacking the ij part of XYZij](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/known-issues). That's why I'm trying to project the XYZ part using the camera intrinsics projection, [wich is explained in the official C API Dokumentation](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reference/struct/tango-camera-intrinsics). My current approach looks like this:

```
    float fx = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.fx);
    float fy = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.fy);
    float cx = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.cx);
    float cy = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.cy);

    float k1 = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.distortion[0]);
    float k2 = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.distortion[1]);
    float k3 = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.distortion[2]);

    for (int k = 0; k < xyz_ij->xyz_count; ++k) {

        float X = xyz_ij->xyz[k][0];
        float Y = xyz_ij->xyz[k][1];
        float Z = xyz_ij->xyz[k][2];

        float ru = sqrt((pow(X, 2) + pow(Y, 2)) / pow(Z, 2));
        float rd = ru + k1 * pow(ru, 3) + k2 * pow(ru, 5) + k3 * pow(ru, 7);

        int x = X / Z * fx * rd / ru + cx;
        int y = X / Z * fy * rd / ru + cy;

        // drawing into OpenCV Mat in red
        depth.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = 240;

    }
```

[image]

The resulting depthmap can be seen in the lower right corner. But it seems that this calculation result in a linear representation ... Does anyone has already done something similar? Are the XYZ points already correct positioned for this projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found a solution ... Just skipped the distortion calculation like they do in the [rgb-depth-sync-example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/rgb-depth-sync-example). My code now looks like this:

```
    float fx = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.fx);
    float fy = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.fy);
    float cx = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.cx);
    float cy = static_cast<float>(ccIntrinsics.cy);

    int width = static_cast<int>(ccIntrinsics.width);
    int height = static_cast<int>(ccIntrinsics.height);

    for (int k = 0; k < xyz_ij->xyz_count; ++k) {

        float X = xyz_ij->xyz[k * 3][0];
        float Y = xyz_ij->xyz[k * 3][1];
        float Z = xyz_ij->xyz[k * 3][2];

        int x = static_cast<int>(fx * (X / Z) + cx);
        int y = static_cast<int>(fy * (Y / Z) + cy);

        uint8_t depth_value = UCHAR_MAX - ((Z * 1000) * UCHAR_MAX / 4500);

        cv::Point point(y % height, x % width);
        line(depth, point, point, cv::Scalar(depth_value, depth_value, depth_value), 4.5);

    }
```

And the working OpenCV result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why did you multiply your xyz index by 3? In: `float X = xyz_ij->xyz[k * 3][0]`

Comment: I think you could also write `float X = * ( * ( xyz_ij->xyz + k * 3 * sizeof(float) ) + 0 )` which makes clear that you need jump for the size of 3 float values.