# Accessing depth camera available for Android phones

Tags: java, android, python, c++, ios

Is it possible to access the third camera from libraries like openCV for an Android phone? Or the depth camera is protected for system usage or root apps?

Comment: What does iOS & Python have to do with this question? What third camera/depth camera on which devices are you referring to? If Google Tango then this may apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901155/project-tango-depthmap-transformation-from-xyzij-data

Comment: I am just asking, if it is possible to use the depth camera from external app, because I didnt find any camera app on Play Store which can do depth feature, I doubt even it is possible.

Comment: Depth camera is rather specialized hardware so either its part of the platform (Tango) or its not. Any app in the Google Play Store that can use a depth camera would be a Tango app and use Tango hardware. This is getting off-topic. Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, your reply really helped me a lot.

Comment: Project tango is shut down. I just need a way to access depth data for Android phones that happen to have those cameras!